# Call JS function onclick

Tags: javascript, html

The sample code below loads a page with a "Show 3D" clickable div. Onclick, it should load a 3D viewer and display associated data.

```js
function showPDB(path,id) {
  var stage = new NGL.Stage(id, {backgroundColor:'white'});
  stage.loadFile(path).then(function (o) {
    o.addRepresentation("cartoon", {color: 'white' });
    o.autoView();
  });
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ngl@latest/dist/ngl.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#show_0" id="_show_0" onclick="showPDB('https://alphafold.ebi.ac.uk/files/AF-P08047-F1-model_v4.pdb', 'viewport_0')">
      <b>Show 3D</b>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="show_0" class="collapse">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div id="viewport_0" style="width:100%; height:800px;"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

It seems that "Show 3D" needs to be clicked twice for the 3D viewer to load. I would like it to load upon a single click.

I guess this function should be triggered only when the inside of the collapsible element has been fully loaded. I tried to tweak in this direction but I could not find a fix yet.

Comment: `loadFile` returns a promise according to your code. You may need to show some kind of loader or disabled the button until the promise get resolved. Also handle exceptions as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is a collapsible, just give some time to the collapsible to load. TO do that, you can wrap the entire script inside a set timeout like below

```
function showPDB(path,id) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    var stage = new NGL.Stage(id, {backgroundColor:'white'});
    stage.loadFile(path).then(function (o) {
      o.addRepresentation("cartoon", {color: 'white' });
      o.autoView();
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: This seems to make the job perfectly. Thanks!